# Moving SVN repositories data with history as subfolders into another repository

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, svndump

I have some repositories, and I need to transform the content of each one in subfolders of another repository *preserving their history log*... How can I do that?

Comment: The question is quite obscure. You should clarify what do you mean by "transform the content of each one in subfolders of another repository". At first glance tt can be the `svndumpfilter` that will help you: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svndumpfilter/

Comment: For example, I have 4 repos (r1,r2,r3,r4) and I need to copy them all to a new repository (repo-all) preserving the history log of r1,r2,r3,r4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish the task. Depending on Subversion server distribution and task complexity you may find one of them easier or more convenient than the other.

### Filtering repository history with `svndumpfilter` tool

The solution is quite tricky because Subversion repository history filtering works based on paths you specify to include or exclude in a repo dump output. In short you should do the following:

1. Dump your current repositories with `svnadmin dump`,
2. Filter out only needed repository path in the dumps with `svndumpfilter`,
3. Load the filtered dumps to another repository with `svnadmin load`.

You can also use [`svnrdump`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svndumpfilter/) tool (exists in SVN 1.7 and later) to perform the dump and load process remotely. See [`svnrdump dump`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnrdump/c/dump/) and [`svnrdump load`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnrdump/c/load/).

I strongly advise you to read the following articles from the SVNBook related to the process:

1. [Filtering Repository History](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/maint/#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering)
2. [`svnadmin dump`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/dump/)
3. [`svnadmin load`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/load/)
4. [`svnrdump dump`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnrdump/c/dump/)
5. [`svnrdump load`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnrdump/c/load/)
6. [`svndumpfilter`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svndumpfilter/)

Suppose you have repository *C:\Repositories\REPO* and folder */trunk/abc* in this repository. See the sample steps to move folder */trunk/abc* to another repository *C:\Repositories\REPO2*.

1. Ensure that all commits that affect */trunk/abc* path and its descendants do NOT affect any other path. For example, there is no commit which adds files to */trunk/abc* and */another_folder* at the same time or copy files from */another_folder* to */trunk/abc* etc.
2. Create dump of the REPO repository:

   `svnadmin dump C:\Repositories\REPO > REPO.dump`
3. Filter out unnecessary paths from the REPO.dump file:

   `svndumpfilter include /trunk/ABC < REPO.dump > filtered.dump`
4. Create empty */loaded* folder in the *C:\Repositories\REPO2* repository.
5. Load dump to that folder:

   `svnadmin load --parent-dir /loaded C:\Repositories\REPO2 < filtered.dump`

*That's it!*

### Repository replication with `svnsync` tool

The solution is also tricky however a complex repository filtration may be a bit more convenient with it than the approach described above.

The approach is to [replicate the repository with `svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) after configuring [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) rules that deny read access to any paths that need to be filtered out from repository history.

**Unlike `svndumpfilter`, `svnsync` will automatically translate copy operations with an unreadable source path into normal additions, which is useful if history involving copy operations needs to be filtered.**

Comment: Apache Subversion FAQ has been recently updated with another filtering approach: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal

Comment: At step 4 should we create a directory in operating system or create svn directory using `svn mkdir`?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question I decided to create an utility for you that would solve this problem. The utility is based on [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com) library and is situated here
https://sourceforge.net/projects/svnkitfilter

Just run

```
$ svnadmin create svn.repo
$ svnkitfilter SRC_URL_1 file:///path/to/svn.svn --prefix prefix/for/repository1
$ svnkitfilter SRC_URL_2 file:///path/to/svn.svn --prefix prefix/for/repository2
...
$ svnkitfilter SRC_URL_N file:///path/to/svn.svn --prefix prefix/for/repositoryN
```