# How to combine 2 un-related svn repositories each present on a different machine into one repository?

Tags: svn, svnadmin

We have two svn repositories Repo-A on machine 1 and Repo-B on machine 2.

What are the different and ideal approaches to merge the repositories into one in the below mentioned way?,

Merge Repo B machine 2 into Repo-A machine 1 keeping all the history of Repo-B machine 2 intact.

The srucuture for both the repos are as below,

Repo-A,

Root
   --Project1
        --tags
        --branches

--Project2
        --tags
        --branches

Repo-B
   --Project3
        --tags
        --branches

--Project4
        --tags
        --branches

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving SVN repositories data with history as subfolders into another repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563031/moving-svn-repositories-data-with-history-as-subfolders-into-another-repository)

Answer (score 0):

`svnadmin dump` + `svnadmin load` are your best friends

Comment: @Deduplicator - I'm lazy to retype help topics for obvious task

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually i believe i have not present my request in an understandable manner. I will get back to you with the right question.