# moving repository to another subdirectory in svn

Tags: svn, repository, svnadmin

I will start by saying svndumpfilter failed (using this solution: [Moving SVN repositories data with history as subfolders into another repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563031/moving-svn-repositories-data-with-history-as-subfolders-into-another-repository)) I got the error:

```
At line:1 char:30
+ svndumpfilter include \trunk < E:\tmp\test1.dump > E:\tmp\test1filter.dump
+                              ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

after executing:

```
svndumpfilter include \trunk < E:\tmp\test1.dump > E:\tmp\test1filter.dump
```

My problem: I have a few projects as separate repositories as such:

```
RootDir -
     project1
     project2
     project3
     project4
     project5
     project6
```

3 of the projects are for the same company, so I want to move them like this:

```
RootDir -
     project1
     project2
     companyX -
         project3
         project5
         project6
     project4
```

**i.e. I want to move multiple repositories to reside as subfolders in one main repository.**

The repository is in a windows server 2012, and I use remote desktop to run svn command prompt on it.

I'm out of ideas

Comment: The second command should be `svnadmin load`, not `svnadmin dump`

Comment: This actually looks like you're moving projects around within the SAME repository, not moving projects from one repository to another, correct? If so, it's not a duplicate of the "Moving SVN repositories" question.

Comment: mistype, I actually did svnadmin load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i the Windows PowerShell of Windows Server 2012.

I downloaded [Console 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/) and used it instead of the Windows shell.

The solution suggested in "[Moving SVN repositories data with history as subfolders into another repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563031/moving-svn-repositories-data-with-history-as-subfolders-into-another-repository)" did the trick.

for my needs I didn't even need the svndumpfilter part.

Answer (score 1):

- svnadmin can not dump only subtree from repository and can not use logical path to *this* subtree

`svnadmin dump path_to_RootDir\project3 > temp_path_in_disk\dump_file.dmp`

will dump the whole repository, from which you have to extract `project(3|5|6)` with `svndumpfilter include` into one common dump. But you can dump subtrees in one command with `svnrdump dump URL` and get 3 files without pre-filtering

- If you load dump, you have to use `svnadmin load` command
- On load, you have to use physical path to repository-root, not logical path inside repository:

`svnadmin load path_to_RootDir < temp_path_in_disk\dump_file.dmp`

- If you want to change mount-point of data, restored from fump, you have to use `--parent-dir` option of load subcommand

`svnadmin load --parent-dir companyX path_to_RootDir < temp_path_in_disk\dump_file.dmp`

Comment: I tried " svnadmin dump https://my_site.com:8443/svn/test1/ > E:\tmp\test1.dmp" > e:/tmp/test.dmp
I got this error: "svnadmin: E205000: 'my_site.com:8443/svn/test1/' is a URL when it should be a local path"×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: @Clonimus - dump and load work with **PHYSICAL PATH** to repository on *local filesystem*, not with URLs

Comment: I did `svnadmin dump E:\ServerFolders\Development\Repositories\test1 > E:\tmp\test1.dmp` and it worked, but:
`svnadmin load E:\ServerFolders\Development\Repositories\test2 < E:\tmp\test1.dmp`
gave me this error:

`At line:1 char:63
+ svnadmin load E:\ServerFolders\Development\Repositories\test2 < E:\tmp\test1.dmp
+                                                         ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported`

Comment: @Clonimus - full dump, restored into existing repo (and if contents of repos are related) *may* have strange effects (if`test2` is fully functional per se) - never tried it. Try to filter dump (leave only needed folders) and|or load it with --parent-dir

Comment: @ Lazy Badger - thank you, what does it mean load it with parrent-dir? how does that work, I didn't quite understand from the docs. BTW test2 is an empty repository (only folder structure - trunk, tags & branch)

Comment: I think the problem is that original **project3** is a repository and **project3** in **companyX** (which is a repository) is just a folder inside a repository

Comment: @Clonimus - no, basename of repo means nothing in your case. `--parent-dir` is NEW mount-point of root for your dump: you dumped from root of repo, but want to to restore into another node (not root)

Answer (score 0):

### Note: this solves a different problem than intended by the question, which was actually asking about moving a set of repositories into subdirectories of a *different* repository.

It looks like you're moving projects around within the same repository, not moving between separate repositories. If this is the case, then I think you just want to use the `svn mv` command using two URL arguments. E.g. `svn mv --parents http://example.com/RootDir/project3 http://example.com/RootDir/companyX/project3 -m "consolidate company X projects"`. The "--parents" option creates the intermediate directory if it does not exist.

Comment: Just for sake `svn mv --parents ...`

Comment: Thanks, adding to the answer. Some versions of the svn book don't include a link for that option :-)

Comment: I got this error "svn: E200007: Source and destination URLs appear not to point to the same repository." which is silly.
I used as source: "my_site.com:8443/svn/test1/"
and as destination: "my_site.com:8443/svn/tests/mytest1"
In the first try the destination was not created (I was wondering if the mv command will create it) and on the second try I created it before executing

Comment: OK, that certainly looks like it may actually be two separate repositories then. You said in your question you had "a few projects in [your] repository" but it looks like actually you have a few repositories on your server. SVN mv will not work between repositories.

Comment: @Ben - So what will, in the simplest way? thank you for your answer

Comment: I think the problem is that original **project3** is a repository and **project3** in **companyX** (which is a repository) is just a folder inside a repository

Comment: Yes exactly. You should probably edit the question to make that clear.